# Hiding Boot Logo on Samsung Galaxy Tab3 Lite SM-T116BU

Tags: samsung, boot, bootloader

I'm trying to hide this Samsung boot logo splash from my tablet

[image]

The closest that I get was trying the method described on this post: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2529133 but after writing the PARAM back to the device, nothing happened.

Trying to solve by myself I started looking at the SBOOT partition on my device, dumped it from `/dev/block/platform/sprd-sdhci.3/by-name/SBOOT` and opened it on a hex-editor, looking at the result I found the "logo.jpg" reference on the hex result, and now comes my question.

[image]

Do you guys have any recommendation/tips on how to avoid the logo.jpg being showed on the device screen? Maybe patching the SBOOT?

Is it too stupid changing the hex from modifying the "logo.jpg" string to avoid the file being located?

Comment: I have the same issue on my Tab E Lite 7.0, it seems like they are hiding in different places now. You should look at this https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2529133
I thought mine was hidden in /dev/block/platform/sprd-sdhci.3/by-name/PARAM , I got all the files extracted, but the screen was not replaced :-( I don't know where else they hide the screen !

Answer (score 1):

That's the easiest way to end up in hardbrick. Don't try that. Remember samsung has no Fastboot mode. If it ends up in HBrick and close you out of Download  Mode, you're ruined totally unless you are a Samsung Hardware and Software Engineer.